# how lawful to have terms of min 5 years in the contract when renting a place for business in california?

Tags: contract-law, california, business

How lawful to have terms of min 5 years in the contract when renting a place for business in California?
Understand that all agreements are between landlord and renter, but still wonder if that is ok to rent a place as business for min 5 years when that place doesn't need any modification.

Comment: Is there a cancellation clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A five year lease of real estate for a business is perfectly normal and lawful in California.

It would probably be more common to lease for one to three years with a right to renew, but there is nothing illegal about a five year term for a real estate lease for a business.

Comment: Or a 99 year lease for that matter